# AsyncTask is an inner class: get onPostExecute() result in Service

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask, sms

Excuse me if my question is similar to others, but i have not got the solution.

I have two classes, MainActivity and SMSMonitorService.

AsyncTask is an inner class of MainActivity.

I want get the onPostExecute result and send it by SMS. The method sendReplySMS is on SMSMonitorService.

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

//some code...

public class DownloadWebpageTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, String> {          

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... urls) {

        // params comes from the execute() call: params[0] is the url.
        try {
            return downloadUrl(urls[0]);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return "Unable to retrieve web page. URL may be invalid.";
        }
    }

    // onPostExecute displays the results of the AsyncTask.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
    //Extract String between two delimiters 
        String finalResult = StringUtils.substringBetween(result, "extract\":\"", "\"}}}}");            
        String finalResponse = StringEscapeUtils.unescapeJava(finalResult);

        textView.setText(finalResponse);     
        SMSMonitorService.sendReplySMS(SMSMonitorService.number, finalResponse); //sendReplySMS and number are declared static                 

    }
}
```

SMSMonitorService.java

```
public class SMSMonitorService extends Service {
//some code...

public static void sendReplySMS(String number, String responseText) {

    SmsManager sms = SmsManager.getDefault();
    sms.sendTextMessage(number, null, responseText, null, null);        
}

//some code..
```

The SMS never send.

How i can send a SMS what contain onPostExecute result?

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: What value does `SMSMonitorService.number`occupy ?

Comment: `number` is the Originating Address.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`SMSMonitorService` is a Service not a normal java class so you need to use `startService` method to start service for sending sms. do it as :

Prepare Intent in `onPostExecute` method for sending all values to `SMSMonitorService` :

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
 //....your code 

  Intent intent = new Intent(CurrentActivity.this,SMSMonitorService.class);     
  intent.putExtra("finalResponse", finalResponse);
  startService(intent);
}
```

and in  `SMSMonitorService` Service use

```
@Override
public int onStartCommand( Intent intent , int flags , int startId )
{
      super.onStartCommand(intent, flags , startId);
      String finalResponse = intent.getStringExtra("finalResponse");
      if( extras != null )
        sendReplySMS(SMSMonitorService.number, finalResponse);
      return START_REDELIVER_INTENT;
}
```

Make sure you have added `SMSMonitorService` Service in `AndroidManifest.xml`

**NOTE:**  Use `IntentService` instead of Service because IntentService stop self when task done. for more information see [IntentService](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html)

Comment: Thanks! But the SMS never sends, i think it's because my phone is dual sim, i'll try in a single sim phone.